# Titanium | How to indent all the code (in Mac)

Tags: macos, titanium, appcelerator

Is there a way by which I can Indent code (complete file) in the titanium IDE? Similar to way in Eclipse.

Is there a keyboard shortcut available?

Comment: command+shift+f works for titanium in mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the MAC, select the window you want to reformat the code in.  At the top select Source->Format and it will also show you the shortcut keys for reformatting the code.  Looks like SHIFT+COMMAND+F on my system.

Answer (score 0):

Select code then Tab and shift+Tab works just as in every other editor

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac you can use the SHIFT+ COMMAND + F to format the file. Before formatting , ensure that you have defined the preferred formatting styles ( the indentation size etc ) correctly  from Preferences ->Titanium Studio ->Formatter->Java Script